# Angular draggable directive not working with AngularUI modal dialog

Tags: angularjs-directive, modal-dialog, draggable, angular-ui-bootstrap

There is an Angular draggable directive [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler).

Can it be applied to an AngularUI modal popup window?

I've created a file called `ngdrag.js` in which I placed the directive code, and that file is loaded in the HEAD section.

```
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ngdrag.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Test1.js"></script>
```

My module includes it:

```
     var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap','ngdrag']);
```

and the html fragment that provides the content for my popup window does this:

```
   <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html" 
        class='modal-window' draggable>
```

but the modal window cannot be dragged.

I can see that the directive is being invoked properly when the page is loaded: the debugger pauses at a breakpoint set in ngdrag.js.

```
 return function (scope, element, attr) {

           <breakpoint here>   var startX = 0, startY = 0, x = 0, y = 0;
```

But the `mousedown` event is not being "heard" by the draggable directive. Does the modal swallow the mousedown event?

Answer (score 2):

I accidentally found this plunker example (not trying to take credits for it - not written by me):

http://embed.plnkr.co/8CHoiN/preview

So you can look at the code an see how it is implemented.

Comment: Use this link, since the link you used has its resources getting blocked and breaks the plunk: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/8CHoiN?p=preview